# How to find the RGB values in QFT

Tags: vbscript, colors, rgb, pixel

I am new at QFT for Testing and VbScript.

I want to get the color value of an certain point.

Is there something like the RGB values to check this in QFT?

Comment: Does QFT refer to [tag:qf-test]?

Comment: i dont know what you mean by qf test

Comment: What does QFT refer to in the context of the question?